# Nodejs exports.module How to export Variable to other Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

my goal is to get a list of files from a google drive folder and its subfolders as json string. so i can then use express to expose it as an API endpoint that other applications can connect to it.

the code is working. i get everything i want, but i do not know how to export my data variable to app.js

```
    // get-filelist.js
var GoogleTokenProvider = require("refresh-token").GoogleTokenProvider,
    request = require('request'),
    async = require('async'),
    data

    const CLIENT_ID = "514...p24.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const CLIENT_SECRET = "VQs...VgF";
    const REFRESH_TOKEN = "1/Fr...MdQ"; // get it from: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
    const FOLDER_ID = '0Bw...RXM'; 

async.waterfall([
  //-----------------------------
  // Obtain a new access token
  //-----------------------------
  function(callback) {
    var tokenProvider = new GoogleTokenProvider({
      'refresh_token': REFRESH_TOKEN,
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET
    });
    tokenProvider.getToken(callback);
  },
  //-----------------------------
  // connect to google drive, look for the folder (FOLDER_ID) and list its content inclusive files inside subfolders.
  // return a list of those files with its Title, Description, and view Url.
  //-----------------------------
  function(accessToken, callback) {
        // access token is here
        console.log(accessToken);

        // function for token to connect to google api
        var googleapis = require('./lib/googleapis.js');
        var auth = new googleapis.OAuth2Client();
        auth.setCredentials({
          access_token: accessToken
        });
        googleapis.discover('drive', 'v2').execute(function(err, client) {

            getFiles()
            function getFiles(callback) {
              retrieveAllFilesInFolder(FOLDER_ID, 'root' ,getFilesInfo);
            }

            function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, folderName, callback) {
              var retrievePageOfChildren = function (request, result) {
                request.execute(function (err, resp) {
                  result = result.concat(resp.items);
                  var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                  if (nextPageToken) {
                    request = client.drive.children.list({
                      'folderId': folderId,
                      'pageToken': nextPageToken
                    }).withAuthClient(auth);
                    retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
                  } else {
                    callback(result, folderName);
                  }
                });
              }
              var initialRequest = client.drive.children.list({
                'folderId': folderId
              }).withAuthClient(auth);
              retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
            }

            function getFilesInfo(result, folderName) {
              result.forEach(function (object) {
                request = client.drive.files.get({
                  'fileId': object.id
                }).withAuthClient(auth);
                request.execute(function (err, resp) {
                  // if it's a folder lets get it's contents
                  if(resp.mimeType === "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"){
                      retrieveAllFilesInFolder(resp.id, resp.title, getFilesInfo);
                  }else{
                    /*if(!resp.hasOwnProperty(folderName)){
                      console.log(resp.mimeType);
                    }*/

                    url = "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+ resp.id;
                    html = '<img src="' + url+ '"/>';

                    // here do stuff to get it to json
                    data = JSON.stringify({ title : resp.title, description : resp.description, url : url});

                    //console.log(data);


                    //console.log(resp.title);console.log(resp.description);console.log(url);
                    //.....
                  }
                });
              });
            }

        }); 

  }
]);

// export the file list as json string to expose as an API endpoint
console.log('my data: ' + data);

exports.files = function() { return data; };
```

and in my app.js i use this

```
// app.js
var jsonData = require('./get-filelist');

console.log('output: ' + jsonData.files());
```

the data variable in app.js doesnt contain any data, while checking the output inside the function getFilesInfo() is working.

so, how to make my data variable accessible in other scripts?

Comment: Did you mean `console.log('output: ' + jsonData.files());`? (Calling the function)

Comment: Yes. Your are right. it should read in app.js console.log('output: ' + jsonData.files()); Thanks.
but still, my data variable doesnt contain any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a problem with sync/async behavior.

app.js should be aware **when** to call the files() function exported from `get-filelist`. The code you've got there calls the files() function immediately after requiring the `get-filelist` module. At that moment the `data` variable is still empty.

Best solution would be to provide the files() function with a callback that will trigger once you've loaded the `data` variable.

Of course, you will need some extras:

1. the `loaded` flag so that you know whether to trigger the callback immediately (if `data` is already loaded) or postpone the trigger once the load is done.
2. the array for waiting callbacks that will be triggered upon load (`callbacks`).

```js
    // get-filelist.js
var GoogleTokenProvider = require("refresh-token").GoogleTokenProvider,
    request = require('request'),
    async = require('async'),
    loaded = false, //loaded? Initially false
    callbacks = [],  //callbacks waiting for load to finish
    data = [];

    const CLIENT_ID = "514...p24.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const CLIENT_SECRET = "VQs...VgF";
    const REFRESH_TOKEN = "1/Fr...MdQ"; // get it from: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
    const FOLDER_ID = '0Bw...RXM'; 

async.waterfall([
  //-----------------------------
  // Obtain a new access token
  //-----------------------------
  function(callback) {
    var tokenProvider = new GoogleTokenProvider({
      'refresh_token': REFRESH_TOKEN,
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET
    });
    tokenProvider.getToken(callback);
  },
  //-----------------------------
  // connect to google drive, look for the folder (FOLDER_ID) and list its content inclusive files inside subfolders.
  // return a list of those files with its Title, Description, and view Url.
  //-----------------------------
  function(accessToken, callback) {
        // access token is here
        console.log(accessToken);

        // function for token to connect to google api
        var googleapis = require('./lib/googleapis.js');
        var auth = new googleapis.OAuth2Client();
        auth.setCredentials({
          access_token: accessToken
        });
        googleapis.discover('drive', 'v2').execute(function(err, client) {

            getFiles()
            function getFiles(callback) {
              retrieveAllFilesInFolder(FOLDER_ID, 'root' ,getFilesInfo);
            }

            function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, folderName, callback) {
              var retrievePageOfChildren = function (request, result) {
                request.execute(function (err, resp) {
                  result = result.concat(resp.items);
                  var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                  if (nextPageToken) {
                    request = client.drive.children.list({
                      'folderId': folderId,
                      'pageToken': nextPageToken
                    }).withAuthClient(auth);
                    retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
                  } else {
                    callback(result, folderName);
                  }
                });
              }
              var initialRequest = client.drive.children.list({
                'folderId': folderId
              }).withAuthClient(auth);
              retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
            }

            function getFilesInfo(result, folderName) {
              data = []; //data is actually an array
              result.forEach(function (object) {
                request = client.drive.files.get({
                  'fileId': object.id
                }).withAuthClient(auth);
                request.execute(function (err, resp) {
                  // if it's a folder lets get it's contents
                  if(resp.mimeType === "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"){
                      retrieveAllFilesInFolder(resp.id, resp.title, getFilesInfo);
                  }else{
                    /*if(!resp.hasOwnProperty(folderName)){
                      console.log(resp.mimeType);
                    }*/

                    url = "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+ resp.id;
                    html = '<img src="' + url+ '"/>';

                    // here do stuff to get it to json
                    data.push(JSON.stringify({ title : resp.title, description : resp.description, url : url}));
                    //console.log(resp.title);console.log(resp.description);console.log(url);
                    //.....
                  }
                });
              });
              //console.log(data); //now, that the array is full
              //loaded is true
              loaded = true;
              //trigger all the waiting callbacks
              while(callbacks.length){
                  callbacks.shift()(data);
              }
            }

        }); 

  }
]);

// export the file list as json string to expose as an API endpoint
console.log('my data: ' + data);

exports.files = function(callback) {
    if(loaded){
        callback(data);
        return;
    }
    callbacks.push(callback);
};
```

Now the app.js behavior needs to change:

```
// app.js
var jsonData = require('./get-filelist');

jsonData.files(function(data){
    console.log('output: ' + data);
});

/*    a much more elegant way:
jsonData.files(console.log.bind(console,'output:'));
//which is actually equivalent to
jsonData.files(function(data){
    console.log('output: ',data); //without the string concatenation
});
*/
```

Comment: Correct! Thank you. it works.
Would had never figured out myself!

Comment: it works, but it only contains one entry and not the whole list.
why is that happen?

Comment: Perhaps you post more of your code so that I can take a look. The data you produce with JSON.stringify will be sent over through the callback. If data contains one entry, callback will get one entry...

Comment: Aha, I see, you use JSON.stringify for each and every entry. I'll soon post a solution to show you how to build a list of entries. The `data` variable needs to become an array instead of a scalar.

Comment: Now that I took more care about the code you were using, I see how the code you took provides support for callbacks. The solution you've got here supports just the "root" folderName. So, the solution can be extended to support subfolders...

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help me.
getting the file list with all its content and files inside sub-folders from google api is working.
where i still struggle is setting my data variable as an array. and then send this array to app.js
i updated your latest code edits and now the data variable (the array) is empty.
before (your first code edits, which correctly transfered my data to app.js) was working. apart of that data was not an array.

Comment: still, the array is empty. i cant find a way to push the data into the array. even after replacing the load procedure

Comment: yes, re-checking the whole load procedure, I see recursive calls, because the whole directory tree gets loaded actually. Try with the original code for fetching the files, but feed it with a callback function - now that you got the point with the callbacks. Try to post a testbed project.